# How to prevent Elasticsearch from matching on only one non-English character with multi_match

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using [elasiticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html) and SmartCN analyzer:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer
analyzer_cn = analyzer(
    'smartcn',
    tokenizer=tokenizer('smartcn_tokenizer'),
    filter=['lowercase']
)
```

And I'm using multi_match to match on several terms:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q
q_new = Q("multi_match", query="SOME_QUERY", fields=["FEIDL_NAME"])
```

The desired behavior is that ES only returns documents with at least two characters matched. I've looked through the documents but couldn't find a way to prevent Elasticsearch matching on a single character.

Any direction / suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 0):

> The desired behavior is that ES only returns documents with at least
> two characters matched.

I am not familiar with `SmartCN analyzer`, but if you want to match on a minimum of 2 characters, then according to your use case, you can use [N-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer) that first breaks text down into words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,    <-- note this
                    "max_gram": 20,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title": "world"
}
```

**Analyze API**

The search query will not match for `"title": "w"`, since the tokens generated are of minimum length 2 (as the `min_gram` is defined 2 in the index mapping above)

The tokens generated are:

```
POST/_analyze

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "wo",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "wor",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "worl",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "world",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "or",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "orl",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "orld",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "rl",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "rld",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "ld",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 9
    }
  ]
}

**Search Query:**

    {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "title": "wo"
            }
        }
    }
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64003025",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.56802315,
        "_source": {
          "title": "world"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi Bhavya, thank you for the response. This approach does not work because we need to use SmartCn to tokenized non-English text. Is it possible to limit the length of the full-text search at **query level** instead of at the tokenization level?